# Is there an online tool to compile LESS?

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) in my webpage, but am having trouble compiling it. It's built to work on ruby, which I don't have permission to install on my pc. Is there an online tool for this compilation?

I know that [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/) exists, but I can't find the demo on their site any longer.

To summarise, I'm looking for a quick and dirty solution to compiling LESS to test my stylesheets locally. Ideally, this would integrate with Microsoft Expression Web 4 (hooray for dreamspark), but I'd be perfectly happy with a "copy, paste, compile, copy, paste" web interface.

Does such an interface exist?

Comment: Why not use LESS in client side mode where javascript does the LESS "compilation"? http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage

Comment: @MatthewLock: Because the site will look terrible with javascript disabled.

Comment: "I'm looking for a quick and dirty solution to compiling LESS to test my stylesheets locally. "

Comment: @MatthewLock: Oh, good point. I asked this almost two years ago - don't expect me to remember what I wrote! The problem with that is that lessjs supports a slightly different dialect to lessphp, which is what I run on the server.

Comment: try simpless at http://wearekiss.com/simpless this work best for win,mac even on linux.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The demo feature on lessphp is [still there](http://leafo.net/lessphp/#demo).

Answer (score 22):

I don't want to advertise my own stuff, but it answers the question and it's open source! I made this about two weeks ago - [The Online LESS Converter](http://www.dopefly.com/less-converter/less-converter.html).

Blog entry: ["Try the LESS converter, right now!"](http://www.dopefly.com/techblog/entry.cfm?entry=352)

GitHub project: [NathanStrutz/LESS-Converter](https://github.com/NathanStrutz/LESS-Converter)

Comment: it works, but it doesn't support the @import clause, you have to merge all of your files to use this tool.

Comment: Right, it can't @import from multiple inputs because it's just one text field. If you can think of a suggestion to fix it, please let me know on the github project page. We can work on it and make it awesome.

Comment: please be aware.. @import "../.htaccess"; will import files from your server :/ suz

Answer (score 6):

**Less2CSS**
http://www.less2css.org
Website is open-source: http://github.com/brian-frichette/less-preview

My co-worker and I needed the same functionality, so we whipped up this online compiler.

**Highlights:**

- CSS is updated in **real-time,** as-you-type, completely client-side.
- You can choose between **LESS versions** (ie. v1.3.3, v1.3.0, etc)

Comment: As for now, http://www.less2css.org does not work. This may be a temporary issue, though.

Comment: Thanks for the notice!  It should be back up now.

Comment: It seems to be down again.

Comment: :( Unfortunately, I don't maintain the site, and I no longer work with the guy who does.  I created a GitHub issue, so hopefully he'll get it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I added a larger syntax highlighting editor and compiler to the lessphp page: http://leafo.net/lessphp/editor.html

Comment: using this and keep getting warning: ""Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/leaf/public_html/lessphp/src/lessc.inc.php on line 282""
Any reason what may be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

There is also [win less (for windows)](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler), which seems to work better for me than [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/#demo).

Answer (score 2):

Recommended list form [less official website](http://lesscss.org/usage/#online-less-compilers):

#### Online Less Compilers

- [less2css.org](http://less2css.org/)
- [winless.org/online-less-compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler)
- [lesstester.com](http://lesstester.com/)
- [dopefly.com/less-converter](http://www.dopefly.com/less-converter/less-converter.html)
- [lessphp.gpeasy.com/demo](http://lessphp.gpeasy.com/Demo)
- [leafo.net/lessphp/editor](http://leafo.net/lessphp/editor.html)

#### Online Web IDEs/Playgrounds with Less support

- [CSSDeck Labs](http://cssdeck.com/labs)
- [CodePen](http://codepen.io/)
- [Fiddle Salad](http://fiddlesalad.com/less/)
- [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)
- jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Here is an online converter i developed recently.

Please give it a try and let me know what you think.

http://www.marcdonaldson.com/less-2-css-online-converter/

My website is still undergoing development and will contain a lot of useful tools once I have developed them ;).

Kind Regards
Marc Donaldson

Comment: Link is dead ... only a background image with a failed-to-load image.

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io

change the css tab (the one in the middle) to use LESS syntax, then paste your LESS code, and click on tab title to see a preview of the compiled css.

plus you get a lot of nice things there, to preview the results live, sharing, integrating with github gists, etc.

Comment: +1 - Wow, I didn't know I could do that!  Nice little Easter-egg!

Comment: It would be nice if you could get a live-update of the CSS, instead of having to click the tab.  Maybe I'll write the JS to accomplish this.

Comment: Ok, I created a pen that outputs the compiled CSS, giving you a live-preview of your LESS: http://codepen.io/scottrippey/pen/liFnc

Answer (score 1):

LessTester (http://lesstester.com/) is an online LESS compiler that also does CSS minification. Very nice for deploying CSS code developed in LESS.

Answer (score 0):

http://incident57.com/less/ LESS app
or
http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/ LESS.js (my preference, since you can link it from google, however it does not run locally).

Answer (score 0):

There is(was?) also http://onless.duostack.net/ but currently the server seems to have some difficulties...

However, source code is here: https://github.com/chendrix/onless.git

Answer (score 0):

These are basically GUI LESS compilers. 
https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/wiki/GUI-compilers-that-use-LESS.js

My personal favorite is Crunch. It's in ADOBE Air format.

Answer (score 0):

For mac, just use: http://incident57.com/less/

For windows, use: http://winless.org/