# SimpleLESS and LESS CSS syntax / validation fail; another pair of eyes to see why this is not working?

Tags: less

SOLVED:  Use [WinLESS](http://winless.org/) instead of SimpleLESS.

---

I am using the [Semantic Grid System](http://semantic.gs/) (which is awesome) and I am trying to use [SimpleLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) to pre-compile my LESS stylesheets into CSS (because [PyroCMS](http://www.pyrocms.com/) 2.1 will not let me set a pass a parameter to set a stylesheet to 'type=text/less"--Pyro mandates that all stylesheet links become "type=text/css"'--and because of that I cannot include the "less.js" file).

I want to add that this WAS working using the less.js...

Anyway, SimpleLESS seems to work on plain old LESS files, but something in this one yields "undefined on line undefined" and will not compile:

```
@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/less/reset.css';
@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/less/grid.less';
@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/less/site.less';

@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/uomless.css';
@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/%23fish/superfish.css';

//////////
// GRID //
//////////

// Specify the number of columns and set column and gutter widths
@basefont: 16;

@columns: 12;
@column-width: 60;
@gutter-width: 20;

// Comment the definition below for a pixel-based layout
@total-width: 100%;


html {

}

body {
    position: absolute;   /*top-most container absolute sections inherit for relative position of descendants */
}

// center the contents
div.center {
    width: 88%;  /* No pixel-width limit, but we want side margins  */
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header, section, aside, footer, nav, tickr, login, rads, gads {
    z-index: -1;        /*z-inex must be negative for plane breaking: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/ */
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

header {
    .column(6);
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    height:auto !important;
    height: 130px;
    min-height: 130px;
    max-height: 130px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

dashboard {
    .column(6);
    margin-top: 12px;
    height:auto !important;
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

login {
    .column(3);
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}


nav {
    .column(12);
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}



footer {
    .column(12);
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}


section {
    .column(7);
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

appspace {
    .column(12);
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

aside {
    .column(3);
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

rads {
    .column(2);
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}


tickr {
    .column(10);
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    header, section, aside, footer, nav
    {
        .column(12);
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to validate LESS to find syntax errors?

Any help would be appreciated.

Shameless

---

Thanks for the suggestions; I have tried the following with no change in SimpleLESS error message:

```
@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/less/reset';
@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/less/grid';
@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/less/site';

@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/uomless.css';
```

also:

```
@import 'less/reset';
@import 'less/grid';
@import 'less/site';

@import 'uomless.css';
```

and:

```
@import 'grid';
```

---

Comment: Please post an answer to your own question and accept it instead of posting solution in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because a CSS import reference is not changed, so the server will retrieve them normally. A LESS import tries to actually pull that file and include it directly in the document, so your path should be relative to the document that is doing the importing, since that import is actually run when the LESS is compiled, not when it is retrieved from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in those two lines

```
@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/less/grid.less';
@import '/addons/shared_addons/themes/base/css/less/site.less';
```

(also you have `%23fish` but I assume it's not in your original code, so skip it)

The only files that are in `@include` and end with `.less`, but I can't tell you why is this happening.

Try renaming the files and/or experiment without .less extension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; See edits to post for test results.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, but grid.css and site.css works ... haha it seems that SimpLess can't import LESS files. Damn! It's in pure JS btw, you could check out the source and post a github issue [here](https://github.com/Paratron/SimpLESS/tree/master/Resources)

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of a way to validate LESS to find syntax errors?

I see you're on a mac: I love Codekit for this - it validates and dislays errors as it precompiles the files you set it to watch.

http://incident57.com/codekit/

If you're using less with node, errors are (I think this is the default) printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://lesstester.com/ (online LESS checker) when I cannot see the syntax error in my LESS.
***Quick*** *and* ***Easy***

There's another SO thread with online LESS checkers: [Is there an online tool to compile LESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763830)